How do I claim My Claynosaurz NFT that I minted when I bought my Solano "Saga Phone "
When I purchased my Saga phone, I was allowed to mint 1 NFT from the (Claynosaurz:The Call of Saga) #10 was the one that I minted!
I forgot about it for a while, but I remembered it a few months ago when I ran across the paper that I wrote it down on!
So , my question is:How do I claim my NFT .I have the hash number of the transaction ,I just need to know how to claim it and get it in my wallet!!!
Can someone Please HELP?
I can locate the Collection on Opensea, but I can't locate the one that I minted! Much less go about claiming it!
SINCERELY, LANCE C FARTHING 

